# How to format LabelString in Lyx .module file?

Tags: formatting, lyx, document-classes, lyx-layouts, modules

## MWE

```
Style Brief_Name
  Category                Pleading
  LatexType               Command
  Align                   Left
  Margin                  Dynamic
  LabelType               Static
  LabelString             "Brief Name: "
  LatexName               BriefName
  LabelFont
    Series                Bold
    Size                  Normal
  EndFont
End
```

## This MWE creates this: [image]

## Whereas I'm looking to create something more like the Kona-Script Letter V2:

[image]

## I'm looking for an answer that helps me change in my MWE:

1. Add a space after "Brief Name"
2. Change the margin setting so that the LabelString "Brief Name" is flushright to a certain degree